# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate

Tags: maven, maven-3

I'm currently learning maven. I use maven 3.0.4.

When using maven to generate a new richfaces project from archetype (doing archetye:generate), it says it was unable to build maven plugin because of missing POM files for org.apache.maven.shared:maven-invoker:jar:2.0.11 and org.apache.maven.shared:maven-script-interpreter:jar:1.0.

It tells so that unable to build the maven-archetype-plugin.

I can access from my http brower the maven2 repo where the maven-script-interpreter and maven-invoker.

Here is the command line and the errors. Thank you!

```
    D:\dev\testRichfaces>mvn archetype:generate  -DarchetypeGroupId=org.richfaces.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=richfaces-archetype-simpleapp -DarchetypeVersion=4.2.0-SNAPSHOT -DgroupId=org.docs.richfaces -DartifactId=new_project
[INFO] Scanning for projects..
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom >>
>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom <<
<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom --
-
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.shared:maven-invoker:jar:2.0.11 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.shared:maven-script-interpreter:jar:1.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.066s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Apr 26 15:20:23 GMT+01:00 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2
.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Execution default-cli of go
al org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate failed: Plugin o
rg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2 or one of its dependencies co
uld not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.m
aven.shared:maven-invoker:jar:2.0.11, org.apache.maven.shared:maven-script-inter
preter:jar:1.0: Failure to find org.apache.maven.shared:maven-invoker:jar:2.0.11
 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, reso
lution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed
or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

Comment: the problem arose from a filtered http access. I have changed location and the problem was solved. I think a corporate level firewall..

Comment: I just accessed maven repo outside my company ! the problem was due to a misconfigured filtering there. Thank you for the interest !

Answer (score 0):

Answered in comments:

> the problem arose from a filtered http access. I have changed location
>   and the problem was solved. I think a corporate level firewall.. – 
>   Brahim Gaabab Apr 27 '12 at 16:14      What did you change it to? – 
>   KenB Jun 27 '12 at 19:59
>
> I just accessed maven repo outside my company ! the problem was due to
>   a misconfigured filtering there. Thank you for the interest ! – 
>   Brahim Gaabab Jul 7 '12 at 17:08